# How to recognise the differance between a "News Post" and a "Page" programmatically with PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, search, modern-experience, pnp-powershell

I have an intranet and try to get the statistics of News Posts. I have now this PowerShell script below where I do a search query and get some metadata.

Is there some attribute where I can recognize it is an News Post?

[image: Add News Post or Page]

```
$CSVFile = "C:\Temp\intranetStats-30-1-2024.csv"
$intranetSites = @()

$intranetSites += "https://myCompany.sharepoint.com"
$intranetSites += "https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/teams/assetmanagement"
$intranetSites += "https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/teams/humanresources"
$intranetSites += "https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/teams/finance"

#Collect Data from search results
$Results = @()

foreach ($intranetSite in $intranetSites) {
    $SearchQuery = "Path: $intranetSite/SitePages"

    #Connect to PnP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $intranetSite -Interactive

    $SearchResults = Submit-PnPSearchQuery -Query $SearchQuery -All -TrimDuplicates $False -SelectProperties Path, Title, ViewsLifetime,ViewsLifetimeUniqueUsers, ViewsRecent, Author, Write, UniqueId, SPWebUrl, SiteId, ContentTypeId
    
    ForEach ($ResultRow in $SearchResults.ResultRows)
    {    
        $Results += [pscustomobject] @{
            Title = $ResultRow["Title"]
            Path = $ResultRow["Path"]
            ViewsLifetime = $ResultRow["ViewsLifetime"]
            ViewsLifetimeUniqueUsers = $ResultRow["ViewsLifetimeUniqueUsers"]
            ViewsRecent = $ResultRow["ViewsRecent"]
            Author = $ResultRow["Author"]
            Write = $ResultRow["Write"]
            UniqueId = $ResultRow["UniqueId"]
            SPWebUrl = $ResultRow["SPWebUrl"]
            SiteId = $ResultRow["SiteId"]
            ContentTypeId = $ResultRow["ContentTypeId"]
        }
    }
}

$Results | Export-Csv -Path $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `PromotedState` property for identifying the site page vs new post in SharePoint.

Where:

- `0`: Page
- `2`: News post

**Example**:

```
$CSVFile = "C:\Temp\intranetStats-30-1-2024.csv"
$intranetSites = @()

$intranetSites += "https://myCompany.sharepoint.com"
$intranetSites += "https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/teams/assetmanagement"
$intranetSites += "https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/teams/humanresources"
$intranetSites += "https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/teams/finance"

#Collect Data from search results
$Results = @()

foreach ($intranetSite in $intranetSites) {
    $SearchQuery = "Path: $intranetSite/SitePages"

    #Connect to PnP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $intranetSite -Interactive

    $SearchResults = Submit-PnPSearchQuery -Query $SearchQuery -All -TrimDuplicates $False -SelectProperties Path, Title, PromotedState, ViewsLifetime,ViewsLifetimeUniqueUsers, ViewsRecent, Author, Write, UniqueId, SPWebUrl, SiteId, ContentTypeId
    
    ForEach ($ResultRow in $SearchResults.ResultRows)
    {    
        $Results += [pscustomobject] @{
            Title = $ResultRow["Title"]
            Path = $ResultRow["Path"]
            PromotedState = $ResultRow["PromotedState"]
            ViewsLifetime = $ResultRow["ViewsLifetime"]
            ViewsLifetimeUniqueUsers = $ResultRow["ViewsLifetimeUniqueUsers"]
            ViewsRecent = $ResultRow["ViewsRecent"]
            Author = $ResultRow["Author"]
            Write = $ResultRow["Write"]
            UniqueId = $ResultRow["UniqueId"]
            SPWebUrl = $ResultRow["SPWebUrl"]
            SiteId = $ResultRow["SiteId"]
            ContentTypeId = $ResultRow["ContentTypeId"]
        }
    }
}

$Results | Export-Csv -Path $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much!

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you! Keep using this platform to ask any questions related to SharePoint.