# Restrict PnPSearchQuery to just site and subsites not all tenant sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, search, pnp-powershell, sharepoint-online-powershell

I had a request from some co-workers to build them a PowerShell to search sites for instances of text that is not accessible so they can replace it. Specifically NA or N/A.

I have a PowerShell working after doing some research. The issue is that the sites are from the entire SharePoint tenant instead of just the site and its subsites to keep things at a smaller level and easier to manage and tackle the script is below. How can I restrict the search to just be the site and its subsites.

I've removed the full URL for reasons. I tried to first restrict it to just the site pages library and then further using the SiteId but results were still the same.

```
$url="tentant/sites/siteUrl"  
$keyword='N/A OR NA'  
$currentTime=$(get-date).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");  
$outputFilePath="C:\results-"+$currentTime+".csv"  
#$credentials=Get-Credential  
 
## Connect to SharePoint Online site  
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -Interactive 
 
## Executes an arbitrary search query against the SharePoint search index  
$results=Submit-PnPSearchQuery -Query $keyword -Refiners "contentclass:0x01010007F4C7534B47E89A77154B10AD7C7C4372 SiteId:{redacted}
 
## Get the results in the hash table  
$hashTable=@()  
foreach($resultRow in $results.ResultRows)  
{  
    $obj=New-Object PSObject  
    $resultRow.GetEnumerator()| ForEach-Object{ $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty $_.Key $_.Value}  
    $hashTable+=$obj;  
    $obj=$null;  
}  
 
## Export to CSV  
$hashtable | export-csv $outputFilePath -NoTypeInformation  
 
## Disconnect the context  
Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use try using `Path` property in your search query to limit search results to specific SharePoint site.

For example:

```
$results=Submit-PnPSearchQuery -Query "N/A OR NA Path:https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/teams/humanresources"
```

**Reference**: [How to recognise the differance between a "News Post" and a "Page" programmatically with PowerShell?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/311063/how-to-recognise-the-differance-between-a-news-post-and-a-page-programmatica/311073#311073)

**Documentation**: [Submit-PnPSearchQuery](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Submit-PnPSearchQuery.html?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

Comment: Awesome I will definitely give this a try. While it works if I dont restrict it somehow it just runs forever as we have a ton of sites and I want to make it as easy as possible to just go site by site.

Comment: Sure, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: That worked like a charm all results in the export are from that site which is fine. I also noticed a new issue which may have resulted in the results being large in the first place is the part where I am searching NA. N/A is fine but NA matches any instance of those two letters. Is there a way to set it match NA so results don't return words with 'Na na'

Comment: Check this docs for query building: [Building search queries in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/general-development/building-search-queries-in-sharepoint?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) and [Keyword Query Language (KQL) syntax reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).

Comment: Awesome I will take a look thank you soo much!

Comment: I updated my script to do "NA" after reading some documentation which I believe should treat NA as a word. Than you again so much for your help!